# Cannot connect to Data, on Tableau Server, from Tableau Desktop

Tags: tableau-api, data-connections

The client gave me a Tableau Server link, let's say, https://example.com.
The aim is to connect tableau desktop to the data on this tableau server. But these weird things are happening -

1. The link does not load in the browser with and without the "client VPN". But the link opens if I use "Zenmate extension" on my browser (Zenmate is a VPN extension).
2. When i try to connect to the link using tableau desktop, it displays a message that "Please check the server name and port and try again". The client, who is in another country, can easily open the link with and without the "client VPN"

I have not worked on Tableau Server and thus not sure as to why this can be happening.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. The link does not load in the browser with and without the "client VPN". But the link opens if I use "Zenmate extension" on my browser (Zenmate is a VPN extension).

Use the Zenmate extension for all your in-browser needs.

> 2. When i try to connect to the link using tableau desktop, it displays a message that "Please check the server name and port and try again". The client, who is in another country, can easily open the link with and without the "client VPN"

The Zenmate Extension most likely only works as a VPN within your browser. Perhaps try a VPN client that actually runs within your OS. I'm on a Mac and I use [Microsoft Remote Desktop](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18140) or [Cisco AnyConnect](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cisco-anyconnect/id392790924?mt=8).

The client may be able to connect with or without a VPN connection because of firewall rules that allow his IP address through.

Comment: Hi

There was some IP issue from the client side and this has not been resolved.
Thanks.